# Golang TCPConn Gob Communication

Tags: go, tcp, gob

I'm having issues with the gob protocol (or maybe networking in general, where my knowledge is weak), and I don't understand why the following code does not work properly. It is just supposed to be a simple example of maintaining an open TCP connection, and sending multiple gobs through it. The code will send, and receive, but often corrupts its data. 
Thank you in advance.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/gob"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

type Message struct {
    Msg string
}

func main() {
    gob.Register(new(Message))

    clientAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "localhost:12346")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    serverAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "localhost:12345")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    serverListener, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", serverAddr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    conn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", clientAddr, serverAddr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    serverConn, err := serverListener.AcceptTCP()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    done := false
    go func() {
        for !done {
            recieveMessage(serverConn)
        }
    }()
    for i := 1; i < 1000; i++ {
        sent := Message{strconv.Itoa(i)}
        sendMessage(sent, conn)
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    done = true
}

func sendMessage(msg Message, conn *net.TCPConn) {
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(conn)
    err := enc.Encode(msg)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

func recieveMessage(conn *net.TCPConn) {
    msg := new(Message)
    dec := gob.NewDecoder(conn) // Will read from network.
    err := dec.Decode(msg)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Client recieved:", msg.Msg)
}
```

Comment: Corrupts its data *in what way*? How often is "often"?

Comment: The output of the example was once:gob: unknown type id or corrupted data
Client recieved: 
Client recieved: 979
Client recieved: 981
gob: unknown type id or corrupted data
Client recieved: 
gob: unknown type id or corrupted data
Client recieved: 
...

Comment: The example is locally executable (run it and see for yourself) :)

Comment: I asked because presumably you've already run it and have the information - if you want help from the community, it's best to include as much detail as possible rather than expecting others to do the work.

Comment: Fair enough (I should have made a playground link myself, but @Cerise-Limón already has one fixed up.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the decoder can buffer data from the next message. When this happens, the next new decoder starts in the middle of a message.  The fix is to use a single encoder and decoder.

```
func main() {
    ...
    dec := gob.NewDecoder(conn) // Will read from network.
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(serverConn)
    go func() {
        for !done {
            recieveMessage(dec)
        }
    }()

    for i := 1; i < 1000; i++ {
        sent := Message{strconv.Itoa(i)}
        sendMessage(sent, enc)
    }
    ...
}

func sendMessage(msg Message, enc *gob.Encoder) {
    err := enc.Encode(msg)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

func recieveMessage(dec *gob.Decoder) {
    msg := new(Message)
    err := dec.Decode(msg)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Client recieved:", msg.Msg)
}
```

[Run it in the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nKuMozXYd6)

Comment: great example. one more question , how to detect that the gob message is coming fresh new on the server side, when the client halt a while than send a new message(gob)